# Join dataframes matching a column with a range determined by two columns in the other one with PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a df on the left like this one:

```
+----+-----+
|  id|value|
+----+-----+
|   2|   xx|
|   4|   xx|
|  11|   xx|
|  14|   xx|
|  27|   xx|
|  28|   xx|
|  56|   xx|
|  55|   xx|
+----+-----+
```

And another one on the right like this one:

```
+-----+---+----+
|start|end| ov |
+-----+---+----+
|    0|  9|   A|
|   10| 19|   B|
|   20| 29|   C|
|   30| 39|   D|
|   40| 49|   F|
+-----+---+----+
```

And I need to join the rows when the id of the first table is between the range of start end of the second table. The output should look like this:

```
+----+-----+----+
|  id|value| ov |
+----+-----+----+
|   2|   xx|   A|
|   4|   xx|   A|
|  11|   xx|   B|
|  14|   xx|   B|
|  27|   xx|   C|
|  28|   xx|   C|
|  56|   xx|    |
|  55|   xx|    |
+----+-----+----+
```

How can I achive this result with PySpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `between` operator with **`left join`**.

**`Example:`**

```
#using dataframes api
df.join(df1,(df['id'] >= df1['start']) & (df['id'] <= df1['end']),'left').select(df["*"],df1['ov']).show(10,False)


#using spark sql api
df.createOrReplaceTempView("t1")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("t2")    
spark.sql("select t1.*,t2.ov from t1 left join t2 on t1.id between t2.start and t2.end").show()    

#this is just sample data
#+---+-----+----+
#| id|value|  ov|
#+---+-----+----+
#|  2|   xx|   A|
#|  4|   xx|   A|
#| 55|   zz|null|
#+---+-----+----+
```

Comment: One quick side note, if the join conditions are not equality conditions, it triggers cartesian product between the dataframes. If either of the dataframes is large, it helps to create a dataframe on the right side of the join that has one row per id value, so the join is optimized.
```df = (df
      .withColumn('id', f.explode(f.sequence(f.col('start'), f.col('end'))))
      .select('id', 'ov')
     )```